# Python Hash function and Hash Object

Tags: python, hash

What is the different between hashable and hashobject in python?

Comment: Ask us something specific. What do you expect us to say that didn't already come up when you Googled `Python hash`?

Comment: This is not a tutoring service. Ask specific questions.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga well i edit my Quiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Hashable**

  - In general means an object has a hash value that never changes in its lifetime and can be compared to other objects. Thanks to those two features, a hashable object can be used as a key in a generic hash map
  - in python mmutable built-in objects are hashable while mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not. User-defined objects are by default hashable
- **Hashtable**

  - in general, hash table (hash map) is a data structure used to implement an associative array, a structure that can map keys to values. Each key given a hash value through hash function for lookup
  - in python, dictionary is an implementation of hashtable
- **hash()** in python

  - hash is a hash function that gives you a hash value (for the key inputed)

    ```
    In [1]: hash ('seed_of_wind')
    Out[1]: 8762898084756078118
    ```
  - As mentioned already, this distinctive 'id' is very useful for look up
  - in theory, a distinctive key will generate a distinctive hash value

By hash object, do you mean by hashable object? If so, it is covered above